# Язык выводимых данных Faker'ом в Laravel Factoryes

Tags: php, laravel

В Laravel встроен faker и после установки уже существует готовый класс для заполнения готовой таблицы в файле 'UserFactory.php', содержащий:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
  return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
    'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
  ];
});
```

Отсюда вопрос как изменить язык данных, в оф документации все написано конечно же но как это применить сюда?

```
$faker = Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');
```

И еще небольшой вопрос, так и не понял как он отсюда определяет в какую таблицу заносить данные, не вижу явной связи c таблицей 'users'.
Из командной строки вызываем:

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> factory(App\User::class, 10)->create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы поменять язык глобально, в `AppServiceProvider::register()` добавьте:

```
$this->app->singleton(\Faker\Generator::class, function () {
    return \Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');
});
```

Если в конкретном случае нужен другой язык, то можно создать новый генератор на месте:

```
$faker = \Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');
```

> так и не понял как он отсюда определяет в какую таблицу заносить данные

Модель знает, в какую таблицу их заносить.